# Topmenu add extra elements

Tags: magento2.2, navigation, topmenu

I am trying to add the category description in the main navigation dropdown for the level 1 child and for level 2 I want to display as a list the product names, so far, I have made a plugin `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Topmenu.php` with follwogin content

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;

/**
 * Plugin for top menu block
 */
class Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Catalog category
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
     */
    protected $catalogCategory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver
     */
    private $layerResolver;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $catalogCategory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->catalogCategory = $catalogCategory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Build category tree for menu block.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject
     * @param string $outermostClass
     * @param string $childrenWrapClass
     * @param int $limit
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
     */
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        $rootId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId);
        $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategory();
        $mapping = [$rootId => $subject->getMenu()];  // use nodes stack to avoid recursion
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $categoryParentId = $category->getParentId();
            if (!isset($mapping[$categoryParentId])) {
                $parentIds = $category->getParentIds();
                foreach ($parentIds as $parentId) {
                    if (isset($mapping[$parentId])) {
                        $categoryParentId = $parentId;
                    }
                }
            }

            /** @var Node $parentCategoryNode */
            $parentCategoryNode = $mapping[$categoryParentId];

            $categoryNode = new Node(
                $this->getCategoryAsArray(
                    $category,
                    $currentCategory,
                    $category->getParentId() == $categoryParentId
                ),
                'id',
                $parentCategoryNode->getTree(),
                $parentCategoryNode
            );
            $parentCategoryNode->addChild($categoryNode);

            $mapping[$category->getId()] = $categoryNode; //add node in stack
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add list of associated identities to the top menu block for caching purposes.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeGetIdentities(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject)
    {
        $subject->addIdentity(Category::CACHE_TAG);
        $rootId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId);
        $mapping = [$rootId => $subject->getMenu()];  // use nodes stack to avoid recursion
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            if (!isset($mapping[$category->getParentId()])) {
                continue;
            }
            $subject->addIdentity(Category::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $category->getId());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get current Category from catalog layer
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    private function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        $catalogLayer = $this->layerResolver->get();

        if (!$catalogLayer) {
            return null;
        }

        return $catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
    }

    /**
     * Convert category to array
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $currentCategory
     * @param bool $isParentActive
     * @return array
     */
    private function getCategoryAsArray($category, $currentCategory, $isParentActive)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $category->getName(),
            'id' => 'category-node-' . $category->getId(),
            'url' => $this->catalogCategory->getCategoryUrl($category),
            'description' => $category->getData('description'),
            'has_active' => in_array((string)$category->getId(), explode('/', $currentCategory->getPath()), true),
            'is_active' => $category->getId() == $currentCategory->getId(),
            'is_parent_active' => $isParentActive
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Category Tree
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @param int $rootId
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function getCategoryTree($storeId, $rootId)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setStoreId($storeId);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('description');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => '1/' . $rootId . '/%']); //load only from store root
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1);
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        $collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
        $collection->addOrder('level', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $collection->addOrder('position', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $collection->addOrder('parent_id', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        $collection->addOrder('entity_id', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

the `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenu" disabled="true" />
        <plugin name="catalogTopmenuImage" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" />
    </type>
</config>
```

and the block where I override the `_addSubMenu` protected function

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Html page top menu block
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Top menu data tree
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node
     */
    protected $_menu;


    /**
     * Topmenu constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param NodeFactory $nodeFactory
     * @param TreeFactory $treeFactory
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        TreeFactory $treeFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory,$treeFactory,$data);
        $this->_menu = $nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [],
                'idField' => 'root',
                'tree' => $treeFactory->create()
            ]
        );
    }


    protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
    {
        $html = '';
        if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
            return $html;
        }

        $colStops = null;
        if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
            $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
        }

        if ($childLevel == 1) {
            $html .= '<div class="submenu-content">';
            $html .= '<div class="menu-cat-info">';
            $html .= '<p class="menu-cat-name">' . $child->getName() . '</p>';
            $html .= '<p class="menu-cat-description">' . $child->getDataByKey('description')  . '</p>';
            $html .= '</div>';
        }
        $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';

        $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
        if ($childLevel == 2) {
            $html .= '<div>' . $child->hasProducts() . '</div>';
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';
        if ($childLevel == 1) {
            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

}
```

the thing is I don't get the category description for the `level 1 child` and I need some pointers on how to get child products.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `description` part looks to be some kind of magento bug, regarding the `addAttributeToSelect` , it uses the `inner join` and it should use `left join` so the description getting should be done something like `addAttributeToSelect('attribut','left')` and for getting products in the menu, I overriten the `getHtml()` function in the block , I used dependency on `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;` and `Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory` to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in loop

```
            $categoryId = $child->getData('id');

             $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
             $catObject = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
             $description = $catObject->getDescription();
```

Comment: I did that at first, it is not working, the `description` is not added to the object itself in the first place

Comment: can you check the code in `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Topmenu.php` the `getCategoryAsArray` and `getCategoryTree` functions, here it should be somehow included, I wouldn't go with the object manager version, I already use the Category model in my plugin but I can't get the category description to show, I am not sure  but I don;t think that the use of `objectManager` is neccesary here